# select option from select box click save button perform database update

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I have a select box with three options. When an option is selected a save button is then click which performs a database update on the field. This will involve having two submit buttons in one form. I have created a different action on each submit button, this will be the save button:

```
if ($_POST['update_status'] == 'Save') {
    $keys = array_keys($_POST['order_status']);
    //perform the database update to change the option value
} 

if(isset($_POST['order_selected'])) {
    //send email 
}
```

At the moment my select box for each option is embedded in a table like:

```
echo '<select name="order_status[] id="id"">';
echo '<option value = "Pending"  name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "pending"' .        ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Pending</option>';
echo '<option value = "Approved" name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "approved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Approved</option>';
echo '<option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status['.$i.']" class ="disapproved"' .    ($row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Disapproved</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

now at the moment I have the update query working, except it is outside of the form and works by posting a unique order I.D from the database and then performing he update. however I can only do 'approved'. 'pending' is not an issue as I have already set a flag in the database when an order is created, as default pending.

Instead of have this functionality outside of the form, I would like to be apple to select a dropdown item, hit save, and then the database update query is run changing the value in the select box, within the same form, if this would be possible?.

at the moment I have the query and submit button outside of the form which looks like:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $id = intval($_POST['approval']);
        $query = "UPDATE Orders SET status = 'Approved' WHERE id = $id";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
    $query = "SELECT ID, Orderno, status FROM Orders WHERE status = '0'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="approval">
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Orderno']; ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" action ="" value="Approve Order" />
```

Many Thanks, any pointers on how I should be tackling this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confused by your question, but if you are trying to have the database query run without having the user leave the page, and then update the attributes of some of your HTML elements, you are going to have to use AJAX.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, At the moment I am approving an order, refreshing the page and the changes are present. That would be optimal, I will continue looking. Thanks